# using lineTo in a movieclip having a some shape already

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

This is quite silly, but still i am scratching my head on this :

```
mc.graphics.lineStyle(2,0xff0000)
mc.graphics.lineTo(100,100);

mc.setChildIndex((mc.getChildAt(0)),0)
```

In the above mc is a filled rectangle shape. But when i use lineTo, it draws line at the back of the shape. I tried to use the setChildIndex method, but of no use.

Any suggestions ? 
Thanks
V.

Answer (score 3):

graphics is the drawing layer below all children within a component, instead you can create another sprite then add it to the display tree in whatever order you please and draw on it's graphics instead.

Let me know if this doesn't help or isn't clear.

Shaun